# How do I combine a LibreOffice numbered list point and sub-point on one line?

Tags: libreoffice

Default LibreOffice numbered lists look like this:

`1. List point
  a) sub-point
  b) sub-point
2. Next point...`

**What I want to achieve is this:**

`1. a) sub-point
    b) sub-point
2. Next point...`

Best I can do so far is this:

`1. (blank line here, looks silly)
  a) sub-point
  b) sub-point
2. Next point...`

Can a number and its sub-list item be on the same line as shown in the middle example above?